# IIS Default wildcard https binding with additional SNI https bindings

Tags: ssl, iis, https, azure-cloud-services

We are running a multi tenant web application in azure cloud service. Customers can register their own instance of our service and get a subdomain. We have bound our wildcard certificate with empty hostname. This works good as our certificate is served now for every https request.

Now the tricky part is that we want to enable our so called enterprise customers to have their own domain/url. It seems though that our wildcard certificate is served for any url even if we have a SNI binding for a customers certificate on for example something.customer1.com.

Dunno if IIS10 would help here? http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support. Even if so, i dunno when IIS10 will be available for azure cloud services.

To summarize we want to be able to bind something like this and wonder if possible somehow:

- *.ourservice.com (our wildcard certificate)
- something.customer1.com (standard certificate)
- customer2.com (another standard certificate)
- etc

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit the binding that uses your wildcard certificate so that it is set to "All unassigned" rather than a specific IP address - otherwise it gets in the way of the SNI site, as you are experiencing.